# Nativescript's Label - doesn't update its width according to a new value?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, stacklayout

I'm facing a wierd width problem.I'm using the Groceries sample app from Nativescript's Docs.

Looking at the bottom label : "sign up here" :

[image]

- We do see all the content.

Now - if a user clicks that Label - there is a new text instead :

```
     <Label width="auto" [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up here' : 'Back to login'"  ></Label>
```

But now look what happens :

[image]

The width is not adjusted to a longer text and instead put `...` at the end.

So I've made an experiment : what if the initial text were long enough at first place ?

So I did this :

```
 <Label width="auto" [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up here22222' : 'Back to login'"  ></Label>
```

So initially it's :

[image]

And hooray -

[image]

I see all the content. - But this is an ugly hack.

**Question:**

How can I set the label width to automatically show all content without cropping ?

---

**Additional Info :**

Css for that Label and its stacklayout :

```
.sign-up-stack {
    background-color: #311217;
}
.sign-up-stack Label {
    color: white;
    horizontal-align: center;
    font-size: 15;
    border-radius:10;
     border-color:#FF0000;
    border-width: 1;

}
```

Comment: try to place a `<br>` tag

Comment: @Aravind why BR ? I don't want any new line ! I want to see "back to login" in one line

Comment: my bad. sorry. about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is :

```
.sign-up-stack Label {
    ...
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And :

```
<StackLayout #signUpStack
                     class="sign-up-stack"
                     (tap)="toggleDisplay()"
                     translateY="50">
            <Label [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up here' : ' Back to login'"       ></Label>
        </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `textWrap="true"` to that label ?

Comment: I don't want new line. I want to see it in a single line.Instead of "'Sign up here'" -  I want to see : "'Back to login'"